# spring boot: cookie not present on browser

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, session-cookies

I've a frontend that needs to reach backend to get token inside a cookie.

In order to get that, frontend tries to send a request to `backend/gicar` and `backend/gicar` responds with a `REDIRECT`.

So, cookie have to be accessible on frontend after redirection.

Here my code:

```java
/**
 * Build cookie with name to carry content 
 */
private ResponseCookie buildCookie(String cookieName, String cookieContent, String site) {
    ResponseCookie accessTokenCookie = ResponseCookie.from(
        cookieName,
        cookieContent
    )
    .httpOnly(false)
    .secure(false)
    .domain(site)
    .path("/")
    .sameSite("Lax")
    .maxAge(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
    .build();

    return accessTokenCookie;
}
```

Above code is reached after a `backend/gicar` endpoint is requested:

```java
/**
* Tries to extract header looking up {@link GicarController.GICAR_ID_HEADER} from {@code request}.
* @param request
* @return Value of {@code gicarHeader}. Otherwise, {@code ""}
    * @throws GitException
    * @throws IOException 
*/
@GetMapping("/gicar")
public ResponseEntity<Void> gicar(
    @NonNull @RequestHeader(GICAR_ID_HEADER) String gicarId,
    HttpServletResponse response
) throws GitException, IOException {
    Usuari usuari = this.authenticationService.getByCodi(gicarId).orElse(null);

    if (null != usuari) {
        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PermisUsuari permisUsuari : usuari.getPermisos()) {
            String instrument = permisUsuari.getInstrument().getCodi().toLowerCase();
            String rol = permisUsuari.getRol().getCodi().toLowerCase();

            scopes.add(String.join(".", instrument, rol));
        }

        ResponseCookie accessTokenCookie = this.buildCookie(
            COOKIE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            this.jwtProvider.generate(gicarId, scopes),
            this.redirectionURI.getHost()
        );
        
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)
            .header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, redirectionURI.toString())
            .header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, accessTokenCookie.toString())
            .build();
    }
    else {
        throw GitException.builder()
            .reason(GitReason.SERVICE_SECURITY_USER_NOTFOUND)
            .build();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm setting `.httpOnly(false)`...

However, when I'm getting cookie on browser:

[image]

Above you can see, cookie is received.

However, cookie is not present on cookies store:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're checking the cookie store of your frontend domain (`frontend-culta-git.apps.ocdes...`) even though the cookies seem to come from your backend domain (`backend-cult...`).

Comment: I've tried to add some more details on post. Shortly yes, frontend is reached after a redirection response from `backend/gicar` endpoint...